# What does it mean to convert a basis in terms of the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If I have a basis of:

$(1,  x+1,  (x+1)x)$

how do I write the basis in terms of the standard basis $(1, x, x^2)$?

The answers tell me I'm supposed to get 3 vectors:

$[1,0,0] , [1,1,0], [0,1,1]$

But I'm not sure how to arrive to that point, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Expand the vectors in the basis by increasing powers. The coordinates are the coefficients of the expanded polynomials.

Comment: Consider a vector (e.g. $v=x+1$) and try to write it as $\lambda_1 b_1+\lambda_2 b_2+\lambda_3 b_3$ where $\lambda_i$ is a scalar from your field (I assume your field here is $\mathbb R$, hence these are real numbers) and $b_i$ is your i-th standardbasis-vector, hence $b_1=1, b_2=x, b_3=x^2$. In our example $v=1\cdot b_1+1\cdot b_2+0 b_3$ hence you write it as $\begin{pmatrix} (1,1,0) \end{pmatrix}$. Now do this with $v_1=1, v_2=x+1, v_3=(x+1)x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should express each basis vector as a linear combination of $(1,x,x^2)$ and take the corresponding coefficients. For example,

$$ (x+1)x = x^2 + x = 0 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot x + 1 \cdot x^2 $$

so the corresponding vector representing $(x+1)x$ with respect to the basis $(1,x,x^2)$ is (in your notation) $[0,1,1]$.